# Exactly the Same Folder again and again inside the sub-folder like a loop

Tags: windows-10, storage, sd-card

I copied my whatsapp folder to my sd card. In the Databases folder of Whatsapp, there is a folder named **&** . When i opened that folder i found the exact files which are in databases folder. The size of the of the "&" folder is 311 GB(Don't know how my sd card size is 8GB) and there are the are 514 subfolders.

There is same folder "&" in the "&" folder & and size of both folders are also same.I don't have any idea how many same folders and files are there in "&" folder.

[image: Here you can see what is happening]

1. How can a folder have more size than it's storage device ?
2. What is happening here "the same folders and files again and again like a loop ?
3. How the **Folder** and Sub-folder have exact same size, the **Folder** contains some other files also except the sub-folder ?

Comment: It was probably an illegal name on the source. Once copied the OS cannot tell where it goes, so it becomes self-referring. Safest bet would be to track it down on the original & eliminate or rename before copying.